# AVFoundation bugs, No sound when I run audioPlayer.play()

Tags: swift, xcode, audio, avfoundation

I have a little problem with AVFoundation, when I launch a sound there is nothing that comes out. On the other hand it is enough to add a timer that displays the currentTime of the sound in question and everything works correctly. could you help me? Thanks.

code that does not work:

```
                     do {
                        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound1", ofType: "mp3")!
                        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

                        let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                        
                        audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
                        audioPlayer.play()
                        
                    } catch {
                        assertionFailure("Failed crating audio player: \(error).")
                        return
                    }
```

just add the timer and everything will work:

```
                    do {
                        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound1", ofType: "mp3")!
                        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

                        let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                        
                        audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
                        audioPlayer.play()
                        print("le son est en cours de lecture !")
                        
                        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
                            print(audioPlayer.currentTime)
                        }
                        
                    } catch {
                        assertionFailure("Failed crating audio player: \(error).")
                        return
                    }
```

Comment: Load the audio file into the memory before playing back the sound.

Comment: How can I do this ?

Comment: and why it works when I add the timer ? this should not change normally

Comment: I just tried with the prepareForPlay() method but it still doesn't work

Comment: your `AVAudioPlayer` is going out of scope and being torn down. assign it to a member variable to extend its lifetime. that's what your timer is essentially doing in the second code sample

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

instead of

`let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)`

change to

`audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)`